# Problemas de OData v4 Client Code Generator en Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, webservice, visual-studio-2015, odata

Hola tengo un problema al momento de realizar la conexión al servicio web usando ODATA, bueno al parecer el web service esta en una Version anterior de ODATA debido a que el datos XML no retorna como JSON, Sin embargo estoy conectándome con visual Studio 2015 usando **OData v4 Client Code Generator** pero me genera el siguiente error :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien tiene idea de como solucionarlo este problema

Por cierto la conexión es mediante https y/o Autenticación

Comment: alguien que pueda ayudarme por favor  es urgente se les agradece por su tiempo...